# Issue with dataframe dates, concat takes too much time, wrong graph output

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I have some question that I can't solve and I really don't understand what's going on.

I have the original dataset **lrdata4**

```html
 year total_vehicles
0 2000 419587299
1 2001 425832533
2 2002 430480581
3 2003 434270003
4 2004 442680113
```

```html
from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

When I do this

```html
lrdata4.year = pd.to_datetime(lrdata4.year)
lrdata4 = lrdata4.set_index('year')
lrdata4.tail(10)
```

The years changes to that and I don't know why. Any help?

```html
total_vehicles
year 
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002009 443333980
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002010 438827716
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002011 440461505
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002012 440073277
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002013 441751395
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002014 451394270
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015 460050397
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002016 470256985
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002017 474693803
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002018 473765568
```

So then i am preparing the model to do the time series forecast

```html
train, test = lrdata4[:-12], lrdata4[-12:]

enter code herescaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train)
train = scaler.transform(train)
test = scaler.transform(test)


n_input = 24
n_features = 1

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train, train, length = n_input, batch_size =1000)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation= 'relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss ='mse')

model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=20)
```

I get the predictions and i append them to a list

```html
pred_list = []

batch = train[-n_input:].reshape((1 ,n_input, n_features))

for i in range(n_input):
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0])
    batch = np.append(batch[:, 1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]], axis=1)
```

And I am trying to concat my original dataframe **lrdata4** and the new dataframe **df_predict**

```html
df_predict = pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(pred_list), index= lrdata4[-n_input:].index,columns=['Predictions'])
df_test = pd.concat([lrdata4, df_predict], axis = 1)
```

But the concat takes forever. I left it for 4 hours and it was still going. Is it because my original dataset have 200k data? Is there another way to do it ?

I've tried plotting them differently like that

```html
plt.figure(figsize= (20,5))
plt.plot(lrdata4.index, lrdata4['total_vehicles'])
plt.plot(df_predict.index, df_predict['Predictions'], color ='r')
plt.show()
```

but the graph is not a line graph with the original data and the predicted data as a continues line graph and the years are wrong which I don't understand why
[This is how the graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDVG9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here the year is an integer - so attempting to convert to a date won't work. If you really want it to be a datetime then you can try and convert the year using something like;

```py
df['year'] = df['year'].apply(lambda x: '{}-01-01'.format(x))
```

and then convert to a datetime using `pd.to_datetime`.